# I can't find the right xpath in a website to use IMPORTXML in Google Sheets

Tags: xml, google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

The website is:
https://www.nordea.no/privat/vare-produkter/sparing-og-investering/fond/vare-fond.html

I'm trying to use the IMPORTXML function on Google Sheets to get the % value under 1d column, of a certain row.

The chrome inspector shows following Xpath for the 1d in the first row:

```
//*[@id="FundList"]/div[4]/ul[1]/li[8]/span[2]
```

which returns #N/A (Import Content is Empty), instead of "1,19%" as for today.

I've tried several xpath "helpers" to find the right one, and modified it many times, men always get empty results.

Comment: this page is built using javascript on client side, therefore you will not be able to use importxml https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun. Try to find another sote or an api.

Comment: Thanks. Sote? this is quite new for me. Any recomendation as a simple start point? It's more than a decade since my last VB program

Comment: If you can't find an api or other url, I'm afraid it's impossible. Maybe via Selenium (I don't practice)